# jQuery function declaration

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between $.myfunc and $.fn.myfunc? I can see one needs return value and use $().myfunc() to invoke while the other one is not. Can the community suggest me some reference or keywords to get more understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$.myfunc refers to a "static" or global function in the jquery namespace. It is not reliant on jquery initialisation via a selector such as $('#id').myfunc(...).

$.ajax is an example.

$.fn.myfunc on the other hand adds myfunc to the prototype of the jquery object, so that when a jquery objetc is created via a selector $('#id') the new object has a method called myfunc that is invokable in the context of the newly created jquery object.

Answer (score 4):

`$.fn` is a shortcut to `jQuery.prototype`. It augments the jQuery object. It is used when working with a set of elements chosen with a selector.

```
$('a').newWindow();
```

I believe assigning a property directly to `$` will make it a utility function, such as `each()` (not tied to a particular set of matched elements).

```
var sum = $.arraySum(array);
```